# creating custom view for 404 error page in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

In my project I want to create custom view for 404 page

setting.py

```
DEBUG = False


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.join(BASE_DIR), "media_cdn")ode here
```

Urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)  
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

handler404 = 'myapp.views.handler404'
handler500 = 'myapp.views.handler500'
```

When I make DEBUG = False in settings.py file, static files not loading properly. Screenshot attached for same.

[static files not loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4qdr.png)

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What does this have to do with the 404 page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `DEBUG = False` your django development `runserver` will [stop serving static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/). You will have to setup a [slightly different way to serve static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development). Remember to remove those patterns for production though. On production setups static files should be served by the web servers such as Apache or Nginx.

Answer (score 2):

If `DEBUG = False`, `static()` will return empty list. So you have to use any web server (apache, nginx, etc) to serve static files.Take a look at

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/deployment/